# a php implementation of a certain jquery script. Finding a parent of p element with text of certain length

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I found this library, php query, and I wanted to know how I can utilize this jquery:

```
var source = $('p:not(:has(iframe))').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().length > 150;})
    .slice(0,1).parent();
```

It finds the the first p element without an iframe that has text longer than 150 characters and takes its parent, I was wondering how I could do this in a php library. I found phpquery, a php implementation of jquery, but I've been confused on how to properly convert this above script.

Comment: Why don't you use a regular expression?

Comment: What's wrong with regex? What's the purpose of the code you're writing?

Answer (score 0):

try using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm 
you can Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
just read the simple manual